# Bootstrap Dropdown menu item uncaughtable

Tags: jquery, python, django-templates, click

I am using Bootstrap 3 with django template and a python background. I am using django variables for the href values in the top navbar dropdown menu. Only one item has got no href attribute, because it does not need to route to other page, it has only one purpose, to show a modal pop-up to the user. So it is just a basic catch-my-mouse-click-with-jquery, where a confirmation question would be asked like "Are you sure you want to to this?", but no matter how I try, I cannot catch the click event :S Any suggestions? I copied here the code from the django template and the javascript file too.

```
        <ul class="nav navbar-nav visible-xs-12 hidden-sm hidden-md hidden-lg">
            <li>
                <a href="{% url 'profiles:email_change' %}">Change Email</a>
            </li>
            <li>
                <a href="{% url 'profiles:password_change' %}">Change Password</a>
            </li>
            <li>
                <a href="#" id="deleteProfil">Delete Profil</a>
            </li>
            <li>
                <a href="{% url 'profiles:signout' %}">Sign Out</a>
            </li>
        </ul>
```

And the script for the catch is

```
        $( "#deleteProfil" ).on( "click", function() {
            $('#deleteProfilModal').modal({show:true});
        });
```

Everywhere else I use this code to catch any click, even on dynamically generated items, it works. Any advices or ideas guys?

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to use an event delegation for this :

```
$('#deleteProfil').on('click', 'li a', function() {
    $('#deleteProfilModal').modal({show:true});                
});
```

also another solution is [`.live()`](http://api.jquery.com/live/) method !

Comment: Probably worth noting that `live` is depreciated.